# Probability for a random variable to be greater than its mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

I'm looking for a general **lower bound** on $\mathbb{P}(X \geq \mathbb{E}(X))$ (or, equivalently, on $\mathbb{P}(X \leq \mathbb{E}(X))$).

### My informal (and naive) reasonning so far

I can think of 2 ways to make this probability arbitrarily small:

1. Stacking all the probability mass on a single point -- consider, e.g.,
   $X_\epsilon = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ w.p. }& 1-\epsilon, \\ 1 &\text{ w.p. }& \epsilon. \end{cases}$
2. Taking a small amount of probability mass to infinity -- consider, e.g., for a given random variable $Y$, the random variable $\tilde{Y}_\epsilon$ obtained from $Y$ according to $\tilde{Y}_\epsilon = \begin{cases} Y &\text{ w.p. }& 1-\epsilon, \\ Y + 1/ \epsilon^2 &\text{ w.p. }& \epsilon. \end{cases}$

These examples suggest that the desired lower bound should depend positively on the variance of $X$ (example 1.) and negatively on the ``diameter'' of $X$ (example 2.), that is,
$$ \text{diam}(X) = \text{sup}~ ( \text{supp}(X)) - \text{inf}~ ( \text{supp}(X)).$$
(To put it simply, assume that $X \in [a,b]$ almost surely and make the lower bound a function of $b-a$.)

**Are you aware of such result? If not, do you think that my hopes are justified, or did I miss a counter-example?**

Edit: A natural candidate would be
$$ \mathbb{P}(X \geq \mathbb{E}(X)) \geq \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{(b-a)^2}. $$
Do you have any specific counter-example for this inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can adjust your $X_\varepsilon$ example *ever so slightly* to get a counter-example to your variance suggestion:
$$
Z_\varepsilon
=
\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{wp} \ 1 - \varepsilon, \\
    1 / \sqrt \varepsilon & \text{wp} \ \varepsilon.
\end{cases}
$$
This has
$$
\mathbb E(Z_\varepsilon)
=
\sqrt \varepsilon
\quad\text{and}\quad
\mathbb V\text{ar}(Z_\varepsilon)
=
\mathbb E(Z_\varepsilon^2) - \mathbb E(Z_\varepsilon)^2
=
1 - \varepsilon.
$$
So, $\mathbb P(Z_\varepsilon > \mathbb E(Z_\varepsilon)) = \varepsilon$ but its variance is approximately $1$.
Of course, higher moments are divergently large (as $\varepsilon \to 0$). If you want the $k$-th momet to be bounded in $\varepsilon$, just replace $1/\sqrt\varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon^{-1/k}$.

This has the propery that the only way of being larger than the mean is to be *enormously larger* than the mean. In particular, it *does not* obey your second condition of having bounded support---well, for fixed $\varepsilon$ it does, but this support as a function of $\varepsilon$ is not bounded.

---

Highly related, but not exactly the same, is the [Paley–Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality):
$$
\mathbb P(Z \ge (1 - \theta) \mathbb E Z)
\ge
(1 - \theta)^2 \mathbb E(Z^2) / \mathbb E(Z)^2.
$$
Obviously, this is useless when $\theta = 0$.

---

Regarding your candidate, which was added after my answer above, I think it can be proved for discrete-valued measures. I expect this can be extended to continuous ones with a density, maybe beyond. Of course, you can rescale to be in $[0,1]$. Also, assume that $Z$ is non-constant, otherwise the variance is $0$ and it trivially holds.

Let $Z = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i \delta_{z_i}$ with $0 \le z_1 \le \cdots \le z_k \le 1$ and $\sum_i p_i = 1$.
Now, let $\mu = \mathbb E(Z)$. Choose $I$ such that $z_{I-1} < \mu \le z_I$. Then, $\mathbb P(Z \ge \mu) = \sum_{i \ge I} p_i$.

Consider the following adaptation to $Z$, which cannot decrease the variance but does not change the probability of being larger than its mean:

> define $Z'$ by moving all the $z_i$ with $i < I$ to $0$ and all with $i \ge I$ to $1$, ie
> $$ \textstyle Z' = (\sum_{i < I} p_i) \delta_0 + (\sum_{i \ge I} p_i) \delta_1. $$
> Let $\mu' = \mathbb E(Z') \in (0,1)$.

Then, the probability of being larger than the mean is unchanged:
$$\textstyle \mathbb P(Z' \ge \mu') = \sum_{i \ge I} p_i = \mathbb P(Z \ge \mu).$$
It shouldn't be so hard to check that the variance cannot decrease, as the mass is pushed further apart:
$$\mathbb V\text{ar}(Z') \ge \mathbb V\text{ar}(Z).$$

Now, $Z'$ is just a $\{0,1\}$-valued random variable. It has mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$, where $p := \sum_{i \ge I} p_i$.
Hence,
$$
\mathbb V\text{ar}(Z)
\le
\mathbb V\text{ar}(Z')
=
p(1-p)
\le
p
=
\mathbb P(Z' \ge \mu')
=
\mathbb P(Z \ge \mu).
$$

One should be able to approximate density functions with such finitely-supported discrete random variables and take limits.

This inequality is tight up to a multiplicative constant, as can be seen by taking a $\operatorname{Bern}(p)$ random variable and letting $p \to 0$. This is natural, because this random variable is unaffected by the above procedure. So, the only inequality which is not tight is $p(1-p) \le p$. But, there does not exist a constant $c < 1$ such that $p(1-p) \le c p$ for all $p > 0$.

Comment: Interesting, even though (as you mention it) in your example the support size increases with epsilon going to 0. Also, you seem to say that the Variance runs *against* us -- I had the opposite intuition

Comment: I've added a candidate for a lower bound. I can't see how to use your technique to disprove it (even when going to higher moments, because then the variance would shrink). Maybe you can prove me wrong!

Comment: @Argemione I'm not saying that the variance goes "against". In fact, I would have the same general intuition as you had, just be aware that there are counter-examples to this. I should note that if the support is bounded in the strong sense of "here's a sequence of random variables; all have support in a fixed $[a,b]$", then the variances must also be bounded: the maximal variance of a random variable on $[a,b]$ is $\tfrac14 (b-a)^2$

Comment: I think you are correct and the last step also proved the sharpness.